# IPhone - Application not showing default message of GPS usage

Tags: iphone, gps

does anybody know a way to show that default alert like ""Your application" wants to use your GPS position"?

My app was showing it by default, but now it's not showing anymore and i'm really afraid my app won't be approved if I don't set it!

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only asks this first time when you want to get users location and remembers the choice. If you want to reset it for testing purposes, go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location Warnings.

Answer (score 2):

It happens automatically when you use the [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123) API. The end user will only be prompted once. If you want to reset this, you will need to do so manually by going to the settings. Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location Warnings. See the *Resetting location warnings* section of this [KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1975) for more details.